# PowerShell git ls-remote exit code 1

Tags: git, powershell

I'm having a problem with my powershell scripts. The following command:

`git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/angular/bower-angular`

Returns a `$LastExitCode` of 1, when it should be 0 since it it sucessful. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't see that here. Are you sure that's the command causing that to be set?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah, I'm sure. Even something as simple as a `git status` has an exit code of 1 for me.

Comment: Kinda sounds like you don't have Git installed. Are you really sure the Git commands are properly running? :)

Comment: But you get the right results from git displayed? How **exactly** are you running the git command? Can you copy and paste the command and output and output showing `$lastexitcode`?

Comment: So I just did a check of which git command was being used: and running `D:\Git\cmd\git.exe status; $LastExitCode` returns 1 and `D:\Git\cmd\git.cmd status; $LastExitCode` returns 0. If that helps

Comment: Are you using ISE or the console?